# Android Force Close issue of Video Recorder implementation in Custom Camera app

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, video-capture

I am developing an Android Custom Camera app and trying to implement the video recorder feature in it. And I am using the below code

```
    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder()
    {
        myCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        try 
        {
            File newFile = File.createTempFile("videocapture", ".mp4", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(newFile.getAbsolutePath());     
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
        try 
        {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But if i use the same code and run it on Galaxy tab, i get a force close at this location of code

```
             mediaRecorder.start();
```

And the error log looks like this.

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=ngcFk

The code works just fine on the same,  when i change

```
   mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

to

```
   mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
```

Not getting why is it so. Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the profile exists. I think for tab it is not supported. You can try that with [hasprofile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#hasProfile%28int%29)

Comment: can u please explain me how to use this hasprofile code exactly?? i tried... But no results!

Comment: hasprofile says weather the profile exists or not. You can check for the return value like if( CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW)){ mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW)); same with QUALITY_HIGH

Comment: Hope you tried the same with QUALITY_HIGH, so the code looks like if(camcoderprofile.hasprofile(quality_high){ setprofile(quality_high); } else if(camcoderprofile.hasprofile(quality_low) { setprofile(quality_low); } This will pick the profile only if the camera supports.

Comment: yes. I tried the same...got this error..      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.media.CamcorderProfile.hasProfile

Comment: Its a method from API Level 11. Pls check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#hasProfile(int, int)